# How to create an uncompressed text file with Athena

Tags: hive, compression, file-format, amazon-athena, presto

I have some data in Athena and I want to join and create a new table. I can do that with as CTAS operation, and [AWS provide a few examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html#ctas-example4).

I'm create output with the `TEXTFILE` format, and I don't want any compression. In this link

> This example also specifies compression as SNAPPY. If omitted, GZIP is used.

Here's an example of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE "main_extended"
WITH (
    external_location = 's3://attr-dev/data-joiner/test-1/main_extended/',
    format = 'TEXTFILE',
    field_delimiter = ',')
AS
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.month
FROM main t1 left outer join period_month t2
ON t1.period = t2.period
```

How do I specify the `compression` option, and what value should that option take to 'turn off' compression for `TEXTFILE` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today this isn't supported with CTAS syntax - have tried multiple approaches, thoroughly reviewed documentation, and also enquired with AWS support.

The recommended approach for creating tables that are backed by simple text files is to invoke a simple `SELECT` statement from Athena and specifying an output location, and then invoking a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` type query which references that output location. The result is the same but the mechanism is a little different.

Comment: I did not get the meaning of the second paragraph. Can we get the uncompressed text file by doing so?